# Ruby longest word in array

Tags: ruby, enumerable, inject

I built this method to find the longest word in an array, but I'm wondering if there's a better way to have done it. I'm pretty new to Ruby, and just did this as an exercise for learning the `inject` method.

It returns either the longest word in an array, or an array of the equal longest words.

```
class Array
  def longest_word
    # Convert array elements to strings in the event that they're not.
    test_array = self.collect { |e| e.to_s }
    test_array.inject() do |word, comparison|
      if word.kind_of?(Array) then
        if word[0].length == comparison.length then
          word << comparison
        else
          word[0].length > comparison.length ? word : comparison
        end
      else
        # If words are equal, they are pushed into an array
        if word.length == comparison.length then
          the_words = Array.new
          the_words << word
          the_words << comparison
        else
          word.length > comparison.length ? word : comparison
        end
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I would do

```
class Array
  def longest_word
    group_by(&:size).max.last
  end
end
```

Comment: if you are sure you have only strings, you can write it as `self.group_by(&length).max.last` else you'd need an additional `to_s` call like `self.group_by{|el|el.to_s.size}.max.last`. And finally, to return a single string when you have only one element, you can do `longest_word.size > 1 ? longest_word : longest_word.first` before returning.

Comment: Nice! I took the liberty of making the code more concise, but please revert if you don't like the style

Comment: The OP said in the question that he did this in order to learn `inject`, and it's not quite clear whether he was looking for a better way using `inject` or just a better way period. Yours is a pretty nice answer to the second interpretation and @Mladen Jablanović's to the first. Both get my +1.

Comment: It started with me toying around with `inject`, but seeing that there are shorter ways to do it without that method is interesting. Thanks!

Comment: @Marc-André Lafortune It is much more readable this way, thanks.

Comment: You might want to check this too [link](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22438653/2125520)

Comment: @IslamAzab `min_by` (and `max_by`) returns just one value, this one returns an array with one or more values.

Comment: @steenslag Since I have seen you getting only the last value, I thought mentioning the other answer is worth it. Thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 7):

Ruby has a standard method for returning an element in a list with the maximum of a value.

```
anArray.max{|a, b| a.length <=> b.length}
```

or you can use the max_by method

```
anArray.max_by(&:length)
```

to get all the elements with the maximum length

```
max_length = anArray.max_by(&:length).length
all_with_max_length = anArray.find_all{|x| x.length = max_length}
```

Comment: That's nice, but the OP "just did this as an exercise for learning the inject method."

Comment: Both methods only return a single element, not an array of some equally length strings.

Answer (score 4):

Here's one using `inject` (doesn't work for an empty array):

```
words.inject(['']){|a,w|
  case w.length <=> a.last.length
  when -1
    a
  when 0
    a << w
  when 1
    [w]
  end
}
```

which can be shortened to

```
words.inject(['']){|a,w|
  [a + [w], [w], a][w.length <=> a.last.length]
}
```

for those who like golf.

Comment: Actually, this *should* work for an empty array, that's (one) of the point(s) of explicitly supplying an initial value for the accumulator.

Comment: In my version, I somehow thought it would be much cleaner to thread the word lengths implicitly through the accumulator, but it hasn't exactly cleaned it up much :-) Yours looks much nicer.

Comment: In order to work for empty arrays, one would have to kickstart `inject` with an empty array (rather than an array containing an empty string as I do), and complicate the branching inside a bit more. But for purpose of learning `inject`, I thought this was enough.

Comment: Ah, yes, it will return a wrong result. I was thinking more about Haskell, where `foldl1` will throw an error while `foldl` won't, or my solution which calls `first` on the result of the `inject`, which would be `nil` for an empty array without an explicit initial accumulator and thus raise a `NoMethodError`. (I should learn to not answer SO questions or leave comments in a rush, with my jacket on, literally halfway out the door :-) )

Answer (score 2):

A two liner:

```
vc = ['asd','s','1234','1235'].sort{|a,b| b.size <=> a.size}
vc.delete_if{|a| a.size < vc.first.size} 


#Output
["1235", "1234"]
```

or if you want use inject, this use your idea, but its more short.

```
test_array.inject{ |ret,word|
   ret = [ret] unless ret.kind_of?(Array)

   ret << word  if word.size == ret.first.size
   ret = [word] if word.size > ret.first.size
   ret
}
```

Comment: This method is not idempotent when applied directly on an array. Probably not what you'd expect. You could use a `clone` here. But the solution is okay, and probably not even the slowest (without knowing implementation details of the `group_by` built-in method)

Comment: @Holger: `group_by` uses array lookups, so it's basically `O(n)`, while the `sort` is slower.

Comment: Instead of `delete_if`, you could use `take_while` which would stop as soon as it reaches a smaller word.

Answer (score 1):

```
module Enumerable
  def longest_word
    (strings = map(&:to_s)).
      zip(strings.map(&:length)).
      inject([[''],0]) {|(wws, ll), (w, l)|
        case  l <=> ll
        when -1 then [wws, ll] 
        when  1 then [[w], l]
        else         [wws + [w], ll]
        end
      }.first
  end
end
```

This method only depends on generic `Enumerable` methods, there's nothing `Array` specific about it, therefore we can pull it up into the `Enumerable` module, where it will also be available for `Set`s or `Enumerator`s, not just `Array`s.

Comment: This returns just one element, not an array of words with equal sizes.

Comment: @steenslag: Yeah, thanks for noticing. The method name threw me off a little, I would have expected a method which returns multiple words to be called `longest_words` (plural).

Answer (score 0):

This solution uses the inject method to accumulate the longest strings in an array, then picks the ones with the highest length.

animals = ["mouse", "cat", "bird", "bear", "moose"]

animals.inject(Hash.new{|h,k| h[k] = []}) { |acc, e| acc[e.size] << e; acc }.sort.last[1]

This returns:
["mouse", "mouse"]