# How can I select the longest string from a Ruby array?

Tags: ruby, arrays, string

However above [duplicate suggestion] is for multidimensional array, not targeting the simpler case I am posing here.

For example if I have:

```
'one','two','three','four','five'
```

I want to select `three` as it is the longest string. I tried:

```
['one','two','three','four','five'].select{|char_num| char_num.size.max}
```

but [Enumerable#max](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-max) doesn't return the right result.

Comment: you have 356 votes in `ruby` tag, at the time of writing

Comment: @emaillenin what a totally uninteresting number

Comment: possible duplicate of [Find longest string in a array?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21911547/find-longest-string-in-a-array)

Comment: @Monk, if you still have your benchmark code, I'd be interested to know how `b = ar.map(&:size); ar[b.index(b.max)]` compares with `ar.max_by(&:size)`.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Monk provided.. But then he deleted.. But I can see it still, you don't :-)

Comment: No, I cannot see it, @Arup.  You must have excellent vision, as I have 20/20.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Actually. I am really able to see it. after 5,000 rep, you can see deleted answer too.. So I am able to see it.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Just do as below using [`Enumerable#max_by`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-max_by) :

```
ar = ['one','two','three','four','five']
ar.max_by(&:length) # => "three"
```

Comment: Can I use `bytesize` vs `length` judging by the tests it is faster?

Answer (score 2):

```
arr.map(&:length).max     -
```

Comment: Please consider expanding on your answer.

Comment: @johnson did you understand the question what the OP asked?

Answer (score 0):

You can also use:

```
['one','two','three','four','five'].inject { |f, s| f.length > s.length ? f : s }
```

Answer (score 0):

I came up with this idea :

```
x = ""
['one','two','three','four','five'].each do |word|
   if word.length >= x.length
      x = word
   end
end

puts x
```